# SQLlite database not working properly in android studio 4

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am learning how to deal with SQLLite database to store data in android studio. I have written the code as below and it should log the 2 entries on the console but its not happening. Can anyone tell me why?

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Users", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name VARCHAR2, age INT(3))");
    myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name, age) VALUES('Sajid', 22)");
    myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name, age) VALUES('Shoaib', 28)");

    Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users", null);
    int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int ageIndex = c.getColumnIndex("age");
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c!=null)
    {
        Log.i("Name", c.getString(nameIndex));
        Log.i("Age", c.getString(ageIndex));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: `VARCHAR2` ? Dont' see that listed as an SQLite type; Check log for any sqlexception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users", null);
int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
int ageIndex = c.getColumnIndex("age");
while(c.moveToNext())
{
    Log.i("Name", c.getString(nameIndex));
    Log.i("Age", c.getString(ageIndex));
}
```